Use StackScreen into Another StackSCreen in React Native TS
React Native Newbie here so i have a SubscriptionStackScreen, and I want to use it in my Subscription in ProfileStackScreen
export type SubscriptionStackParamList = {
  SubscriptionPlan: undefined;
  ProcessPayment: undefined;
  SubscriptionSuccess: undefined;
  MonthlySubscription: undefined;
};

export type SubscriptionRoutesType =
  StackRoutesType<SubscriptionStackParamList>;

const SubscriptionRoutes: SubscriptionRoutesType = [
  {
    name: "SubscriptionPlan",
    component: SubscriptionPlan,
    options: { headerShown: false }
  },
  {
    name: "ProcessPayment",
    component: ProcessPayment
  },
  {
    name: "SubscriptionSuccess",
    component: SubscriptionSuccess,
    options: { headerShown: false }
  },
  {
    name: "MonthlySubscription",
    component: MonthlySubscription
  }
];

and i want to use it in my ProfileStackScreen
const ProfileRoutes: ProfileRoutesType = [
...
];
const ProfileRoutes: ProfileRoutesType = [
  {
    name: "Subscription",
    component: SubscriptionRoutes
  }
];

